# Can "Blood Lust" take me above max damage?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

Samson's starting item, Blood Lust, [increases the the damage of Isaac's tears with each kill](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/70719/23609).

Can it go beyond scale, as some damage multipliers do (i.e. Whore of Babylon)? What I'd like to know is if it has any use if I already reached the cap through other +dmg items (Blood of the Martyr, Growth Hormones, et al.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After conducting some research, I do believe the answer is **no**. Once you have your damage maxed, Blood Lust will not increase your damage further.

On my latest play through with Samson, I picked up the *Small Rock*, *Growth Hormones*, *Blood of the Martyr* and *a Lump of Coal*, so my damage was nice and maxed. I then proceeded to face Gish, who spawns Clots quite frequently. Taking care to hit Gish just once and then proceed to kill a heap of clots before trying that again, it seemed like each of my hits still took down ~9px of Gish's health bar, which was exactly the mount of damage I did straight through the door.

Comment: But what if I already am at the cap? Imagine this situation: I get Blood Lust as first item, then the Rock, Blood of the Martyr, Halo, Growth Hormones(or any combination that brings you to damage cap). Does this make Blood Lust useless, or it becomes more powerful?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean and I completely misinterpreted your question, then. I've actually been playing with Samson quite a bit but have nothing conclusie to say about this in particular. I'll go ahead and murder my answer.

Comment: Updated answer after conducting some research.

Comment: Wait don't you mean that the answer is **no**? The question is "can blood lust take me above max damage" and you're saying that a character at (or near) max damage didn't get an appreciable boost, unless I misread your answer

Comment: @Tacroy it looks like he meant no, otherwise the first sentence contradicts the rest of the answer.

Comment: @Tacroy He's probably answering "Does it have the usual damage cap?" from the question body.

Comment: Man, why do people change the polarity of their question between the title and the body? :(

Comment: @Tacroy Oh man, my bad. I edited the question title to make it clearer, but didn't realize it created this contradiction. I'll fix it right up.

Comment: @Aubergine my bad, sorry about that. Anyway I accepted the answer, especially for using SCIENCE!